# How do I fill out Google applications when their own reCAPTCHA is broken?

Tags: google, recaptcha

I am filling out a Google application:

https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest/

At the bottom it says "reCAPTCHA V1 IS SHUTDOWN", so I do not know how to proceed.

[image]

I tried entering ""reCAPTCHA V1 IS SHUTDOWN" and that did not work.

Is there any way I can proceed now with this form?

Do I need to wait until Google realizes their form needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have heard some reports that:

- Entering the shown text ("reCAPTCHA V1 IS SHUTDOWN") will let you pass.
- Entering any text will let you pass.

But if that's not true, then you'll have to wait until the site is updated.

Tricking the site itself should be impossible for a properly programmed website. Most bypass methods instead rely on convincing reCAPTCHA's API to return a 'success' result. If the API was shut down in such a way that it *never* returns a 'success', that's the end of it.